# How do I install package.json dependencies in the current directory using npm

Tags: deployment, node.js, dependencies, npm

I have a web app: **fooapp**. I have a `package.json` in the root.  I want to install all the dependencies in a specific `node_modules directory`.  How do I do this?

### What I want

Lets say I have two `widget` dependencies. I want to end up with a directory structure like this:

```
node_modules/
  widgetA
  widgetB
fooapp/
  package.js
  lib
  ..
```

### What I get

when I run `npm install fooapp/`  I get this:

```
node_modules/
  fooapp/
    node_modules/
      widgetA
      widgetB
    package.js
    lib/
    ..
fooapp/
  package.js
  lib/
  ..
```

npm makes a copy of my app directory in the node_modules dir and installs the packages inside *another* node_modules directory.

I understand this makes sense for installing a package.  But I don't `require()` my web app inside of something else, I run it directly. I'm looking for a simple way to install my dependencies into a specific node_modules directory.

Answer (score 588, accepted):

Running:

```
npm install
```

from inside your app directory (i.e. where package.json is located) will install the dependencies *for* your app, rather than install it as a module, [as described here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). These will be placed in ./node_modules relative to your package.json file (it's actually slightly more complex than this, so check [the npm docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information)).

You are free to move the node_modules dir to the parent dir of your app if you want, because node's 'require' mechanism understands this. However, if you want to update your app's dependencies with install/update, npm will not see the relocated 'node_modules' and will instead create a new dir, again relative to package.json.

To prevent this, just create a symlink to the relocated node_modules from your app dir:

```
ln -s ../node_modules node_modules
```

Comment: Despite that it is a working solution, I found out `npm link` is more convenient in such situations where you need to grab modules from another directory (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/820520)

Answer (score 20):

In my case I need to do

```
sudo npm install
```

my project is inside /var/www so I also need to set proper permissions.

Comment: sudo may be not required for npm install.

Comment: Depending on the user that needs to execute the js file and dependencies installed, you can run `sudo -u [username] npm install`.

Better to just `npm install` and `chown` the node_modules directory recursively after the fact.

Comment: never run npm with sudo unless you're using `-g` -- and even then there are better ways to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but why is that? can you explain? I mean, what if I have a project in which I want or need to keep a folder with root permissions and install dependencies without -g there? maybe there's a good reason, but I did sudo npm install (without -g) a few times and never got any trouble. Cheers!

Comment: @tkone, after a while I've come to this as a nice solution for Linux/OSX users that want to install globally without sudo: [npm install -g without sudo by Kazé](http://kazhack.org/?post/2014/12/11/npm-install-g-without-sudo). Hope it helps to (L)ubuntu users like me.

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea to use sudo with any command on console except the commands that really require the root permissions.

Comment: @RredCat I agree about the right way of doing this kind of stuff, but after a while I noticed that this discussion is migrating towards Ubuntu, it seems there's a problem in the way it manages some permissions and folders, that is forcing users to use `sudo npm`. Again, only in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Just execute

```
sudo npm i --save
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --force
```

from documention:

> The `-f` or `--force` argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk