# How to specify local modules as npm package dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an application which has the usual set of dependencies on third party modules (e.g. "express") specified in the `package.json` file under dependencies. E.g.

```json
"express" : "3.1.1"
```

I would like to structure my own code modularly and have a set of local (meaning on the file system I am currently in) modules be installed by the `package.json`. I know that I can install a local module by running:

```bash
npm install path/to/mymodule
```

However, I don't know how to make this happen via the package.json dependencies structure. Using the `--save` option in this command is simply putting `"mymodule": "0.0.0"` into my package.json (doesn't reference the filepath location). If i then remove the installed version from node_modules, and try to re-install from the package.json, it fails (because it looks for "mymodule" in the central registry, and doesn't look locally).

I'm sure the is a way of telling the `"dependencies": {}` structure that I want it to be installed from a file system path, but don't know how.

Anyone else had this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: A really good question. Sad to realise that there is no feature equivalent for `package.json` to what we have in `Gemfile`s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local dependency in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json)

Answer (score 762, accepted):

#### `npm install` now supports this

```bash
npm install --save ../path/to/mymodule
```

For this to work `mymodule` must be configured as a module with its own `package.json`. See [Creating NodeJS modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).

As of npm 2.0, local dependencies are supported natively. See [danilopopeye's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/451672). I've copied his response here as this question ranks very high in web search results.

> This feature was implemented in the version 2.0.0 of npm. For example:

```json
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

> Any of the following paths are also valid:

```
../foo/bar
~/foo/bar
./foo/bar
/foo/bar
```

#### syncing updates

Since [`npm install <folder>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#:%7E:text=to%20a%20project.-,npm%20install%20%3Cfolder%3E,-%3A) adds the package in the directory as a symlink in the current project any changes to the local package are automatically synced.

Comment: This worked for me. (I just did a local relative path like `"mymodule":"file:mymoduledir"`

Comment: ```npm install --save ../my-local-repo```

Comment: And how to use it in the project? I'm trying to call it like `import { HelloWorld } from "my-test-lib";`, but i receive "Cant find module" error. Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818083/use-a-local-module-using-local-dependency/46818152

Comment: @LucioMollinedo can you share the syntax of how you imported the local module? As with Vitallii, I'm getting "Can't fine module" error with `import { HelloWorld } from "my-test-lib";`

Comment: This doesn't work the same as referencing a package as dependencies won't be installed to the project

Comment: Same as everyone here, I don't understand how to import the module? Can someone please share that crucial bit of info, and maybe update the answer? Referencing the local module is pointless without also being able to use it???

Comment: If I include the module baz in another module (say main-module), the bar module is not found when I run npm install on main-module. Any solutions for this?

Comment: I tried the same, but it throws the error npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../../../../../WebstormProjects/project-name" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: This works for me. But IDE navigates me to node_modules instead of the actual project file while trying to access the source of import. How do I fix this?

Comment: This works great when I am running locally.  However, when I do a "sam build" it fails with "npm ERR! Could not install from "..\dependencies\nodejs" as it does not contain a package.json file."
What is so special about AWS's sam build command that it breaks?

Comment: The problem is if using Docker you need to list all local dependencies in the Dockerfile

Comment: @inigo why did you add the caveat about syncing updates? I just tried this with npm 6.14.8 on macOS and it creates a symlink therefore updates do propagate automatically.

Comment: This doesn't work in npm any more. There is an [npm issue and repro](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2339#issuecomment-904748108) demonstrating that this doesn't work due to an intentional breaking change starting in version 7.

Comment: For the `can't find module` error don't forget to run `npm build` in the linked package's folder.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko you have to use path to your component you want to use. in my case thats: ` import { SamplesWrapper } from 'samples-wrapper/src/main'`

Answer (score 61):

See: [Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json)

It looks like the answer is `npm link`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: actually npm link will only create the symlinks, and will not modify the package.json to add the local dependency

Comment: But if its not a `symlink` how will the parent project know to rebuild once the dependency has finished building?

Answer (score 16):

I couldn't find a neat way in the end so I went for create a directory called `local_modules` and then added this bashscript to the package.json in scripts->preinstall

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(find ./local_modules -type d -maxdepth 1) ; do
    packageJson="${i}/package.json"
    if [ -f "${packageJson}" ]; then
        echo "installing ${i}..."
        npm install "${i}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just add to your `package.json` file in your project:

```json
"package-name" : "path/to/package"
```

and then run `npm i` in your project.

Answer (score 8):

The following should help (assuming the library and the app share the same the parent folder)

In the **library**:

```
npm pack // this will pack the library in a .tgz file
```

In the **app** that needs the library

```
npm i ../mylibrary/../library-package-X.X.tgz
```

---

This will make the following changes in your **app**

`package.json` will now have

```
 "@mylibrary": "file:../mylibrary/library-package-X.X.tgz",
```

Answer (score 6):

After struggling much with the `npm link` command (suggested solution for developing local modules without publishing them to a registry or maintaining a separate copy in the node_modules folder), I built a small npm module to help with this issue.

The fix requires **two easy steps**.

First:

```
npm install lib-manager --save-dev
```

Second, add this to your `package.json`:

```
{  
  "name": "yourModuleName",  
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/local-link"
  }
}
```

More details at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lib-manager. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

At work we have a common library that is used by a few different projects all in a single repository. Originally we used the published (private) version (npm install --save rp-utils) but that lead to a lot of needless version updates as we developed.  The library lives in a sister directory to the applications and we are able to use a relative path instead of a version.  Instead of "rp-utils": "^1.3.34" in package.json it now is:

```
{ 
  "dependencies": { ...
    "rp-utils": "../rp-utils",
   ...
```

the rp-utils directory contains a publishable npm package

Comment: do you need to perform `npm install` every time you make changes to `rp-utils`?

Comment: Any time you change the imported package you will need to rebuild it and then in the application that uses it `npm update rp-utils` update that dependency.

Answer (score 4):

**use install-local**

I had issues with conflicting react installations from the local dependency.
I solved the error by using `install-local` npm package. This package does not create symlinks, which solved my issue.

**Steps:**

1. run `npm i -g install-local`
2. run `npx install-local --save <local-path>` inside the target repository to install the local dependency

Further reading: https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local

**The error I received, when trying to install the local package with `npm install --save <local-directory>`:**

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: It's `npm i install-local` not local-install

Comment: `npx install-local` is the correct command. I got the words flipped.

Comment: Thank you so much! Took me a day and half until i found this answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved the issue I had with trying any other method. Perfect and thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptible to simply publish your modules preinstalled in node_modules alongside your other files, you can do it like this:

```
// ./node_modules/foo/package.json
{ 
  "name":"foo",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "main":"index.js"
}

// ./package.json
...
"dependencies": {
  "foo":"0.0.1",
  "bar":"*"
}

// ./app.js
var foo = require('foo');
```

You may also want to store your module on git and tell your parent package.json to install the dependency from git: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately that would involve node_modules having my local modules and third party/contributed modules installed from the registry (e.g. connect) in the same directory. Besides that being confusing from a Git/VCS perspective (i.e. would have to ignore all in node_modules except those i created), it's also bad practice (those I have written and aren't published should be kept separate from those others have written and published).

Comment: When I add a local module then make changes these are not seen by my main app. Why is this the case?