# Steps to create node-js client kurento opencv module

Tags: npm, kurento

**What I do** :

1.I used the opencv-plugin-sample(from the link https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample) and start the kuretoMediaServer

2.In the client side I used **js** and **java**,Both works well

3.For js I used the command

```
  cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
  npm install grunt grunt-browserify grunt-contrib-clean grunt-jsdoc grunt-npm2bower-sync minifyify
  grunt
```

to generate the js folder and the dist folder

4.For java I used the command

```
  cmake .. -DGENERATE_JAVA_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
  make java_install
```

**What I have to do**:

1.Now I need to run kurento with android,So I have used the following link https://github.com/apeunit/AppRTC-Kurento-Example

2.In the client side they have used **node-js** to communicate with KMS

3.Now I am trying to add the opencv sample in the existing code,With reference to the link http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html#examples ,I changed the package.json file but it shows the error

```
 'kurento-module-opencvpluginsample' is not in the npm registry.
```

4.When I checked the crowd-detector sample(https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-crowddetector ) ,module(kurento-module-crowddetector) is present in the **node_module** folder,For the opencv-sample

Whether I need to add the module(kurento-module-opencvpluginsample) maually?or

Is there any default steps to generate files in the module(kurento-module-opencvpluginsample) folder as done in java and js above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm resolves packages by name and version by checking with the npm registry (see [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) link for more info) What this line

`kurento-module-opencvpluginsample' is not in the npm registry.`

is telling you, is that it cannot find your module in the npm registry. That's no surprise, as it is only located in your local machine. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies) SO answer about how to specify local modules as npm deps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,the above answer is regarding linking the module wth the npm.But i need the steps to generate node module for opencvpluginsample(kurento-module-opencvpluginsample).Is there any automated steps to generate node module as created for js and java?

Comment: It's generated in the same way. You should see it in the JS folder.