# how to share code between Webpack build and NodeJS server process?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

My application has a directory structure more or less like this:

- `src-program/` - contains frontend code including `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`
- `src-server/` - contains backend code including a different `package.json` and `.babelrc`
- `shared/foo.js` - is JavaScript code that is needed by both the frontend and the backend

All code uses ES2015 syntax and thus is transpiled using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

For the frontend the "transpilation" is done during the Webpack build by using the [babel-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader).

For the backend it is done on-the-fly by [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/).

`shared/foo.js` requires other modules, that are found in the `package.json` files of both the frontend and the backend.

Due to how NodeJS/Webpack resolve modules, the shared module isn't found normally.

---

For Webpack I solved this in a somewhat hacky way using this configuration:

```
resolve: {
  root: __dirname,
  fallback: [
    __dirname + "/../shared",
    __dirname + "/node_modules"

  ],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

The first `fallback` makes sure that the "shared" module is resolved and the second `fallback` makes sure that modules required by the shared module are still resolved to the frontend `node_modules` directory.

This allows including the shared module as simple as this:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';
```

---

However, I'm having difficulties to make the **backend** (ie. NodeJS) resolve the shared module the same way.

I tried with [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path), which makes `foo.js` resolve, but then the file is either not processed by Babel or additional Babel modules like `transform-runtime` (*indirectly* needed by `foo.js`) cannot be resolved since they reside in `src-server/node_modules`...

I could probably work around the problem by pre-transpiling the code instead of using `babe-register` but it all doesn't feel right anyway.

So, **what is a good way to share code between a Webpack build and the NodeJS server process**?

Answer (score 0):

Can you package the shared module up as an npm package (even a package just residing on your filesystem)? Then your `src-program` and `src-server` projects can add it as a dependency in their `package.json`, and it will get copied into their respective `node_modules` folders.

See: [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)