# Install npm local package dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have a npm dependency installed from a local path, which in turn has a few dependencies of its own. As I understand it, in this case npm just copies the contents of the local folder under node_modules. Is there any way to make it run npm install on the package folder before copying it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm install /path/to/foo` simply copies from the specified path into your local package's `node_modules` folder. If this is what you meant by "installed from a local path", then that was the wrong thing to do if you want to make sure that `npm update` and `npm install` on your package would (a) automatically get the latest code from that path and (b) update/install the dependencies of the package at that path.

To accomplish (a) and (b), you can add that local dependency to your `package.json`'s `dependencies` or `devDependencies` (supported by npm since 2.0). For example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "file:/path/to/foo"
}
```

After doing the above, `npm update` or `npm install` will treat that local dependency in the same way as any other dependency.

Comment: I had already saved the dependency on the package.json. The issue I was having was with babel not being found when run on the prepublish hook. moving that to install solved the problem.

Comment: my dependency frequently changes, is there way to update the repository also? even I have incremented version of dependency in dependency package.json and rerun the npm update, local dependecny update is not getting reflected in original project.

Comment: @vishal-mote Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, unable to figure it out.