# npm 5 loses it with node_modules as a symbolic link

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-link

I have a system that builds several node.js projects and maintains the node_modules cache of each project separately. I'm trying to migrate from npm 3 to npm 5 but the issue below is causing a lot of problems.

`node_modules` inside each project is a symbolic link to the real modules directory that is stored and maintained separately. While this worked like charm in npm 3, npm 5 keeps losing itself when `npm install` is re-invoked inside the same location. npm just keeps trying to remove/move everything over and over, and worse lose some packages sometimes.

These commands demosntrate the issue:

```
> cd <proj_folder>
> ln -s $(mktemp -d -p .) node_modules
> npm install grunt
   + grunt@1.0.2
   added 92 packages in 6.122s
> npm install grunt
   + grunt@1.0.2
   added 251 packages and updated 1 package in 7.584s
```

Am I missing something? please assist ..

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install npm local package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774328/install-npm-local-package-dependencies)

Comment: Related: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: @str thanks, but this is unrelated to "npm link" - I am not willing to make a global installation/linkage