# Overriding default npm registry for single packages served from local folder

Tags: npm

I'm adding several dependencies to a project that currently uses the default npm registry. Obviously the dependencies cannot be resolved since the packages are not found there.

I'm wondering if I can provide the packages via a folder or zip file instead and tell npm to bypass the registry for certain dependencies and take the packages directly from the folder. I want to avoid to setup my own registry.

Comment: Maybe you could just depend on the modules directly, using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with reasonable effort because the packages I depend on have more dependencies that would have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia) seems to be a lightweight solution for the problem. It is a private repository server that allows to use private packages, cache the npmjs.org registry, and to override public packages.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tried it because my problem was solved by another private registry I didn't know at the time of writing the question. However, maybe it helps someone else.