# How do I stop npm (v5.3.0) from automatically clearing local modules after install/uninstall?

Tags: node.js, npm

I just upgrade my npm to v5.3.0 and run into a problem: after I install/uninstall a module, npm would automatically clear my local modules that I manually put into my node_modules. These local modules are not included into package.json. This is really annoying. Please help, thanks.

Comment: You might be having an XY problem. You are _not_ supposed to put additional content into node_modules manually. Instead of insisting to change the behaviour of npm, you should find an alternative to your current approach.

Comment: @E_net4 Yeah, my current alternative is to npm link my local modules into node_modules but I would lose the links after cloning. The last alternative is to publish them as private modules?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies

Comment: As well pointed out, there are better ways to specify dependencies that are not in a registry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is similar to the question [How To Specify Local Modules As NPM Package Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies). The command is "npm install [path-to-local-module] --save". The local modules will be copied into the node_modules folder and their dependencies will be added to package.json.