# How to have environment-specific npm load paths?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some node.js libraries that I package as modules and install by `npm install --save`. This is a pain to debug, because I have to publish a module, then update to use the newer version.

I see on this SO question: [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies) that I can specify my dependencies as paths, which is much better.

Is there a way I could create a debug environment that uses paths for mudule-loading, and then a release environment that will use the modules from npm?

In this case the 'release' is created by the command `pkg -t win index.js`. i.e.

1. I'd like to develop with relative paths to modules
2. I'd like to 'switch' to using modules from npm without changing strings anywhere.

Then. If the above is possible, I would like to NOT import the module file to node_modules, but run it in place (I'm trying to take advantage of VS Code debugging)