# Create models just once for both Node.js and angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

I'm learning Node.js along with Angular (a MEAN project) via Udemy, where I've to create identical model for both back-end and front-end(angular2). It makes me wonder if there's a way to create a model that somehow will apply for both sides?

If I need to change a class, then I have to make changes in both, which could have a possibility for missing out a thing or two in the long term.

Comment: You're asking if you can have both a *Front-End* and a *Back-End* accessible to the same Model Schema definition?

Comment: You can have a local dependency used by both front and back, that contains your models interfaces. See: https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies&ved=2ahUKEwiBkLzd9fvYAhUCORQKHepxAEoQjjgwAHoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1jSengeoq8C8FnlZpExxFW

Comment: @TobiahRex Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already had the same question months ago and my answer was: **no**. The reasons:

1. Models are Angular is written in `.ts` files and the server, in `.js`. I thought this difference between extension could lead future problems.
2. Both front-end (Angular) and backend  (Express) should have to share the same folder. I didn't like this idea to put both in the same folder because the project structure would be too large and complex to manage.
3. I was using mongoose. Mongoose schema/model declaration is different from an Angular class declaration, they're incompatible with each other.

These were my consideration about sharing the same file model.

Comment: But now node.js framework `nest.js` give you typescript version of node.js so you cna keep your models in a shared folder from where both front-end and back-end can use those models

Comment: @FahadSubzwari , im trying to do the same at this moment... plz advise if u have any ideas in another answer