# Meteor package use private NPM package

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, atmosphere.js

I have written a private general purpose NPM package. Now I'm writing a meteor package because I need to access mongo collections for example.
I also need to access my private NPM package.

So I created a blank meteor package:

```
meteor create my-package --package
```

and then added my NPM package:

```
// package.js

...
Npm.depends({
  '@myorg/my-package': '1.0.0'
});
...
```

Whenever I try to add this package to my actual app, it gives me the following:

```
error: there is no npm package named '@myorg/my-package' in the npm registry
```

I already tried to put an `.npmrc` file with a valid access-token into the package directory but it didn't seem to work.
Also, when I run `npm whoami`, it shows my username so I'm actually logged in and can, theoretically speaking, access my package.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
I now opened an issue for meteor: [#10102](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10102)

Comment: NPM Depends is a little bit outdated. Maybe you try [tmeasday:check-npm-versions](https://github.com/tmeasday/check-npm-versions) to soft link to your npm package and [manually link the package in your package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies).

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you running? Maybe the `npm` version bundled with that Meteor version doesn't support scopes?

Comment: @FredStark I'm using the latest version of Meteor which is `1.7.0.3`.

Comment: Weird. I would go with @Jankapunkt's recommendation then. Maybe open an issue on the meteor repo too, seems like a bug