# Ignore a custom module from node_modules when npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have 4 modules inside node_modules folder where one of them is a custom module. In my package.json file, I have the other 3 modules specified as dependencies. So now when I do `npm install` node is removing that one custom module from node_modules folder because it is not listed in dependencies inside `package.json` file.

Is there anyway to keep this custom module without node deleting it when I do `npm install`? I've tried to include it in `.npmignore` file, but node is still deleting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your custom module to another directory outside the `node_modules` and add it to your `package.json` as a file reference.

```
"dependencies": {
    "custom-module": "file:custom-module"
    ...
```

Then you can run `npm install` and it will sort out your `node_modules` right.

Comment: How should I then specify the path for that module which now lies inside another folder? I put in it a folder name called server and use ***file:server/custom-module***, but node says it cannot find the module.

Comment: You can let `npm` to figure out the path for you: `npm install --save ../path-to/my-local-repo`

Comment: This completely messed up with git :) It seems like Git has problem with symlink folder. Not just git, but Sublime Text too.

Comment: Have your `node_modules` in `.gitignore`. They are meant to be fetched using `npm install`!