# NPM: Can we store node_modules into a common folder and use it in Angular projects?

Tags: angular, npm, continuous-integration, node-modules, package.json

Can we store node_modules into a common folder instead of  local repository folder(node_modules) and then use this common folder into angular project?
  i will explain my requirement via a flowchart : 
[image]

I know its recommended that **we are highly encouraged to place the dependencies locally in node_modules folders so that they will be loaded faster, and more reliably**.
But still i am trying to create a common local repo(like m2 in maven) which contains modules locally.

- **First of all, is it a good idea ?** (in my point of view if i able to do this, the CD process will be reduced to 2-3 minutes from 20-25 minutes) [ We perform clean build hence agent clears local changes from the repository so `npm install` is required]
- All the dependencies are of fixed version(no upgradation automatically)
- How do I configure npm to store the packages into common folder instead 
  of local node_modules
- How do I import packages present in common repository into my angular 
  codebase

Can anyone help me on this . ??

Comment: You could use `yarn` instead, as `yarn` does cache everything locally, similar to an m2. No need to change the `package.json`, and it still builds a `node_modules` directory https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/

Comment: @user184994 but when i do clean build the cache will be cleared . That's why i want to store node_modules into some other location

Comment: You can set the yarn cache to store in whatever location you want

Comment: cool... then how to i refer that location to import modules ?

Comment: Like with an m2 in maven, when you do `yarn install`, it will first look in the cache location (the equivalent of an m2), and if it finds it, it will copy from there to your node modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by implementing Yarn.

We have to set cache path as . :

```
yarn config set cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
```

After implementing this. I was able to successfully achieve the above mentioned requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1:**

You can move the node_modules folder inside src/lib folder and update package.json to point to local src/lib path. For this to achieve, we need to use yarn.

**Option2:**

You can move all the node_modules to your custom git repo, modify the checkout path to custom git repo in package.json/config.xml. During npm install , it will load from custom git repo.

[how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)