# Local npm dependency with aliases

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/boardgame.io but want to have it as local dependency to be able to debug, modify etc. So i cloned repo and in my app package.json i have 
`"boardgame.io": "file:~/Projects/Games/boardgame.io",`
So far so good, but problem is that package makes use of `exportAliases` when i try for example 
`import { Client } from "boardgame.io/react";` 
i get `Unable to resolve`. It works just fine when i use npm published version of boardgame, so it leads me to suspicion
 that there is some trick i dont know to make such packages working locally (boardgame.io is just example, with other packages problem is the same). Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you built the package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) command.

Example:

```
cd ~/projects/package-to-link  // go into the package directory
npm link                       // creates global link
cd ~/projects/your-project     // go into some other package directory.
npm link package-to-link       // link-install the package
```

Comment: Yeah it helps indeed. Thx a lot.

Comment: Happy coding! Please, don't forget to accept the answer :)