# Google App Engine Not Able To Resolve Relative Path

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying node js API on google App Engine and API is working fine on my local machine but when I run gcloud app deploy command,  I am getting following error

> Cannot find module './src/routes/classes.js' . 
>   I am using below configuration in app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

and getting error on following API line code.

```js
const class_Router =require('./src/routes/classes.js') ;
```

can any one help on this issue ? everything works fine on local but getting this error while deployment. 
Do I need some configuration in my app.yaml file ?

Comment: What version of the Cloud SDK are you using? As well, if you are using `npm` to manage the modules of your application, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/10561875) would solve the issue.

Comment: I am using  Google Cloud SDK 240.0.0
beta 2019.02.22
bq 2.0.42
core 2019.03.22
gsutil 4.37

Comment: Can you try adding your local dependencies in the `npm` `package.json` file, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/10561875)?