# npm install local modules with common dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, local

We're developing an Electron app with a dependency upon an SDK (that we're also developing). Typically, once the SDK is ready, we do a new release and update the Electron app to use it.

But I'd like to make a local change to the SDK and have the Electron app consume it. This is proving problematic.

The approach I took is to, from the **Electron app directory**, run

```
npm install /path/to/sdk/moduleB
```

i.e. Based on the answers to [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

However there's a problem. The SDK's sub-modules registers with a **core** module. i.e. To make an instance available.

When I use a local path to moduleB it cannot find the core module. I don't specify core as a dependency in moduleB. But if I do npm installs a copy under

```
/path/to/sdk/moduleB/node_modules/core
```

rather than re-use the module already defined at

```
./node_modules/core
```

i.e. Even though they're using the same version.

This behaviour (at least the re-installation of core) makes some sense if you understand how npm resolves the same dependency with different versions.

https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b

and

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> npm install :
>
> Install the package in the directory as a symlink in the current project. Its dependencies will be installed before it’s linked. If  sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be hoisted to the toplevel node_modules as they would for other types of dependencies.

But it seems the install creates a symlink and npm can't search back up into

```
./node_modules/core
```

The only way I've been able to work around this is by copying

```
/path/to/sdk/moduleB
```

to

```
./node_modules/moduleB
```

Is there a better solution that'll allow me to re-use the

```
./node_modules/core
```

dependency?