# Do I need to add new package.json in src folder?

Tags: json, react-native, directory

I am beginner programmer. In react-native project I saw some file like package.json in src folder in some project. In file was written `{"name": "src"}`
Besides package.json in file were `app, dev, res` folders.
Is it important for something?

[image]

Comment: `package.json` should be at root level only.

Comment: @ravibagul91 root level you mean in mobile level? In mobile level I have ```package.json``` But in src folder I also have ```package.json```

Comment: I think the file in `src` folder is of no use.

Comment: if its giving some error then run this command in project terminal 'rm-rf node-modules'  after that run this 'npm install'

Comment: Importing local dependencies is supported natively. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies?rq=1