# Local dependencies in a JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Let's assume I have a project structure as follows:

```
packages/
     core/
     client1/
     client2/
package.json
```

All the subpackages are supposed to be   published to a public registry, but  haven't been published yet. Client packages link core package as a local dependency (defined as `file:../core` in their package.json files). Npm documentation suggests using such dependencies locally, which seems logical enough. But is it possible to install a package from local dependency  in one case and from registry in another case, and what's the correct way to handle this in JS world?

Comment: Yarn workspaces could be smth you're looking for: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/. Afaik there's no alternative for npm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)