# How to import module like 'MyOwnLibrary/data'

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, npm

I'm working on a two-package project using Typescript & React-Native:

PackageA(which is leaf package) contains a REST client and mocks

```
MyOwnLibrary
- src
  -tests
    _mocks_
      -restClientMock.ts
  -restClient.ts
```

Right now, I can import stuff using something like 'import { restClient } from 'MyOwnLibrary/lib/tests/_mocks'

But, I want to consume the mocks like `import { restClient } from 'MyOwnLibrary/mocks'`

Any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: I know I could add "paths" in tsconfig in my top level package so that it could resolve correct. I'm wondering if anything could be done in lower package level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tsc -init` command to make tsconfig.json file

Open file and edit baseUrl and paths

```
 "baseUrl": "MyOwnLibrary/src",    /* Base directory */
    "paths": {
      "MyOwnLibrary/mocks" : [    /* Whatever name you want to use */
        "tests/_mocks/restClientMock.ts"   /* Path to your module */
      ]
    },
```

then, you can simply import like this:

```
import { restClient } from 'MyOwnLibrary/mocks' /* Imports from MyOwnLibrary/src/tests/_mocks/restClientMock */
```

Comment: but this import is happening at another pkg, would this work?

Comment: Just like you import node_modules? @SDEZero

Comment: Try this [how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)