# How to import local dependency from node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have done `npm install ./pathtolocalfolder --save`.
My `package.json` has a dependency with name: `file: ../pathtolocalfolder`.

How do I import the folder in my project?
npm can't resolve `./node_modules/folder` or `folder`.

Comment: Why use npm if your file is local? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it works fine.

You don't even need to use `npm install ./testmodule --save` but your module must have package.json

Main ./package.json with reference to testmodule

```
{
  "name": "npmtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "testmodule": "file:testmodule"
  }
}
```

Main ./app.js

```
var testmod = require('testmodule');

testmod.run();
```

./testmodule/package.json

```
{
  "name": "testmodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

./testmodule/index.js

```
exports.run = function() { console.log('testmodule'); }
```