# Lazy import of external js file in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to import external js file in one of my application routes.

```
@(task(function* () {
  yield import('jquery/dist/jquery').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/widget.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/data.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/ie.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/scroll-parent.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/version.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable.js').then(module => module.default);
  yield import('jquery-ui/ui/position.js').then(module => module.default);    
  yield import('pivottable/dist/pivot.js').then(module => module.default);
})) pivotTableRunner;

afterModel(){
  this.get('pivotTableRunner').perform();
}
```

Currently I’ve been importing that library in my pivotTableRunner, but it turned out, that I have had to make some modifications of that library imported from node_modules. I copied it’s content to another file, and placed it in vendor folder. Is there any way to import it lazily after pivotTableRunner task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [the suggested path](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import/issues/158#issuecomment-443063971) for this would be to create a local NPM module and then tell  about it. This would allow you to do

```
async afterModel(){
  await this.get('pivotTableRunner').perform();
  await import('LOCAL_PACKAGE');
}
```

Some good instructions for creating the local module are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/796999)

Comment: You need to use [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) to make this work. It's included in a newly created ember application since some time.