# Can we provide npm install from IIS?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can load files from local directory.
Can we do the same procedure to provide files from IIS?
I have tried, it is always telling the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: http://localhost:7771/.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jeevanandanj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-16T09_58_08_259Z-debug.log
```

[how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies?rq=1)