# How to imitate my library is a node module without uploading to the NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I'm developing a library which work is based a lot around of current working directory and the filesystem generally, a lot of paths resolution, and I want to see how it will behave when will be installed as a node module, I don't want to get unexpected results when I'll upload it to the npm. How do I test my library behavior pretending it's a node module? Is placing its folder in `node_modules` enough?

Comment: Well, yes. After all `node_modules` are just some other code downloaded to your project and get called

Answer (score 1):

Make a local package and install it everywhere:

```
$ npm pack
```

it will generate a zipped file, so you can copy somewhere and install it.

```
// another project
$ npm install /path/to/pack
```

Resources:
[npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack),
[Add local package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

> Absolutely you can use `npm link` too. [link](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-local-package/)