# Can't npm install local dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I've been using `npm install react-financial-charts` successfully. However, I want to include this package locally instead (for reasons), so I checked out the master branch of [`react-financial-charts`](https://github.com/reactivemarkets/react-financial-charts) from Github. I now have two folders:

```
C:\Users\user\projects\react-financial-charts // fresh checkout from Github
C:\Users\user\projects\myproject // my project
```

Inside of my project, my `package.json` contains:

```
"dependencies": {
 "react-financial-charts": "file:C:/Users/user/projects/react-financial-charts"
}
```

`npm run dev` will now encounter the compile error corresponding to a basic import statement `import { BarSeries } from "react-financial-charts"` in one of my files:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-financial-charts' in 'C:\Users\user\projects\myproject\src\App'
```

So basically, the simple import statement which used to work (when I was doing `npm install react-financial-charts`), is now no longer working when I install the dependency from a local folder instead.

EDIT: I also tried these things that an answer below suggested, but I'm getting the exact same error message:

```
npm link ../react-financial charts
```

```
npm install ../react-financial charts
```

```
npm install --save ../react-financial charts
```

EDIT 2: This ended up working, thanks to the suggested answer below. The trick was I needed to `npm update` and `npm install` inside the dependency before linking.

```
cd react-financial-charts
npm link
cd ../myproject
npm link react-financial-charts
```

Comment: This might help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** Using `npm-link`

Go to `C:\Users\user\projects\react-financial-charts` in terminal:

```
npm link
```

Now, go to your project `C:\Users\user\projects\myproject`:

```
npm link react-financial-charts
```

Now, any changes to `C:\Users\user\projects\react-financial-charts` will be reflected in `C:\Users\user\projects\myproject`. Note that the link should be to the package name, not the directory name for that package.

**Method 2:** Saving local repo as `npm-install`

```
npm install --save ../path/to/mymodule
```