# Can a parent node project use packages from a nested node project?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I've got a Firebase project with file structure like so:

```
node_modules/
package.json
functions/
  node_modules/
  package.json
```

If I `npm install firebase` in the parent project, everything works fine locally but the code fails on deployment because the child project is deployed without the parent project yet depends on Firebase.

If I install Firebase in the child project, the parent app complains `"Cannot find module 'firebase/storage'"`

If I install Firebase in both projects, the parent app complains `"Cannot read 'path' of undefined"` - debugging shows this is a Firebase internal error.

My ideal solution is to `npm install firebase` in the child project only, but somehow allow the parent project to access it? Is this possible?

I've read about [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link) but not sure if this can help me or whether there is some other more suitable solution.

Optional reading: Why do I have a structure like this?

I ended up with this structure because the child project is a Firebase project and `firebase init` created the functions folder and its contents. The child project is deployed to Google Cloud.

The parent project is a simple test bed app that I created and uses much of the code in the child project for testing purposes only, this code is not deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from here:

[how to specify local modules as npm package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

I ran this command in the parent project:

```
npm i --save ./functions/node_modules/firebase
```

Which adds an entry to the parent package.json as follows:

```
"firebase": "file:functions/node_modules/firebase"
```

Now everything works!

Obviously, this assumes that the child package is actually installed.

Using a `preinstall` script in the parent package.json to install the child packages first ensures this works smoothly.

My `preinstall` script entry looks like this:

```
"preinstall": "sh preinstall.sh"
```

And the script itself has the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -rf node_modules

cd functions || exit

rm -rf node_modules
npm install --also=dev
```

When you run `npm install` the preinstall script is automatically executed before the actual install takes place.