# Local path dependencies not installing their own dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/4818123), I installed my local dependency like this:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "my_dependency": "../relative/path/to/my_dependency"
  }
}
```

`my_dependency` depends on ESLint and its plugins:

```json
{
  "name": "my_dependency",
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.25.0",
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0"
  },
```

If I install `my_dependency` as a path, `eslint` and it's plugins are not installed in `./node_modules`, therefore `eslint` CLI is not available.

However, if I publish `my_dependency` on npm and install it as package name and version,

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "my_dependency": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

`eslint` and all plugins will be added in `./node_modules`.

How to get the same effect for the local dependency?
I don't want to pollute npm registry with versions just for experiment each time I make changes in `my_dependency`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

Unfortunately those local path packages don't get their dependencies installed.

> note: Packages linked by local path will not have their own dependencies installed when npm install is ran in this case. You must run npm install from inside the local path itself.

Source: [docs.npmjs.com/...](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths)

### The workaround

There are quite a few ways around it but in my opinion the best one is to use a GitHub repo and optionally a branch.

So just push your code to a github repo, let's say `my-npm-playground`, assuming your use your Github username is `ada_lovelace`, you can link the repo like so,

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "my_dependency": "ada_lovelace/my-npm-playground"
  }
}
```