# NodeJs configuring peerDependencies in relative path dependency module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, aws-cdk, peer-dependencies

I have a lib package that has (following [AWS guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/manage-dependencies.html#manage-dependencies-ts-js:%7E:text=versions%20are%20acceptable.-,Construct%20libraries,-If%20you%27re%20developing))

```
"devDependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.1.0"
  },
"peerDependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

It is checked out in parallel with my app package and depended via relative path.

```
"dependencies": {
    "lib": "../../lib",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.39.0"
  },
```

Current behaviour:

1. `npm install` in lib
2. `npm install` in app creates a symblink to lib in `node_module`. `"aws-cdk-lib": "2.1.0"` is used.

Desired behaviour:

1. `npm install` in lib
2. `npm install` in app clones the src of lib, and builds lib in `node_module` with `"aws-cdk-lib": "2.39.0"`

How do I achieve this?

I don't want to use other workarounds like [depending via git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326794) because I don't have an easy way to get git credentials during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend this, but if all you want is the source to be compiled, just import it directly:

```js
import { X } from '../../lib'
```

But you'll have to install the lib's dependencies in your project as well.

Alternatively, you can alias the import path in your `tsconfig.json` by adding:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
        "@lib": ["../../lib/*"]
    }
}
```

And import it as:

```js
import { X } from '@lib'
```

But again, you have to add the libs dependencies to you project's `package.json`.

At that stage, you're better off just copy/pasting the code into your project, that's much less brittle, but still not a great way of managing it.

It's a much better idea to just install the lib via npm. If you don't own the lib, but you do own the pipeline, there are workarounds that might work. For example, it could be easier to clone the repo to codecommit and install it from there, it all depends on what the problem is exactly.

Bottom line is, I wouldn't make a brittle codebase just because your deployment pipeline is tricky, the pipeline is supposed to *help*, not make your life harder.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll bite the bullet and use git module import following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312033). This brittle way causes more problem when there are breaking changes and the consuming package need to depend on a previous major version, since the latest src is always pulled down.

Comment: That's only if you don't specify a commit. You can add the commit id or tag to the end of the URL with a hash, I do it all the time. `"lib": "git+ssh://my.lib.url#<tag id || commit id>"`