# Is there a way to save an NPM package that is no longer on NPM?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am using a package that used to be available on NPM but since then it has been removed from NPM and GitHub.

I still have the package downloaded in my `node_modules` folder.

Is there a way to save that package and keep it in my `node_modules`? I am okay with maintaining the package myself.

It would also be great if I could sync just this specific package with Git so I can share it with my teammates.

Comment: Why not copy it out of your node_modules, and then publish it on github.  Then use the github url in your package.json.

Comment: @StevenSpugin do I need to make changes to the package or can I literally just copy it and upload it to GitHub?

Comment: You can just upload it as is, to your own repo.  Then, npm will let you use github directly. Update the readme with a comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that package as a local module and install it as a package in your application.

Check this out: [Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

Comment: Would I just use npm link in that case or keep the package in the root directory and just use npm install with a direct path to the package?

Comment: npm link does not add in package.json dependencies: []...  You can store that package/module anywhere on your PC, and npm install path/to/mymodule. It will install it in node_modules like other packages. Any changes in that local module will be synced automatically to your project.

Comment: This works. Just needed to do `npm install --save ../path/to/mymodule`. 

Example: `npm install --save ../Downloads/MyPackage`