# Local package dependencies conflicting with the main project dependencies

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, dialog, npm-package

I started learning about how to create our own npm package and i created one. Now in this package, i want to create a dialog box for react native apps using typescript. Here are my files;

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rn-dialog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a simple dialog box package for react native app",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "react-native-dialog",
    "rn-dialog",
    "rn-dialog-box",
    "react",
    "react-native-dialog-box",
    "popup"
  ],
  "author": "Irfanwani <irfanwani347@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=18.0.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.69.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.4",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "ESNext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**index.tsx** (inside the src folder)

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const Dialog = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is from Dialog</Text>
      <Text>Hope it works, inshaallah!!!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Dialog;
```

As you can see my devDependencies to build this component and after installing them, i also get react and react native installed with latest versions.

So when i try to pull this package locally into my project (expo project), it gives an error;

> React Native version mismatch.
>
> JavaScript version: 0.70.2 Native version: 0.69.0

I tried to run npm install --production on my package but it didn't work.

Any help will be appretiated!

Comment: have you tried running `npm start --reset-cache` ?

Comment: yes i did. `npx expo start -c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, i came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375578/13789135) answer and this helped.

We only need a package called `install-local` which installs local packages as other remote packages.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your devDependencies to:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.69",
  "typescript": "^4.8.4"
}
```

Comment: But is it a general solution? What i mean is will it work with bare projects too, or any other project

Comment: This doesn't work