# How to fix "cannot find module {the path to my folder}" when using javascript code (im running it using node .)

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I was writing JavaScript code (just plain 'ol web servers because I am a noobie dev) and I got the above error (Refer to title) and I tried every old way I remembered (as I faced the error in the past) but did it work? Nein. And it came to the point where I am now asking this on Stack Overflow, so uh yeah **help**

What I tried:

I tried like re-opening the file and stuff similar (It resolved the issue for me in the past), I don't even know if this is detailed enough tbh

Comment: You mentioned it write this is not detailed enough. You have to mention what exactly you want to achieve and how you have written your code. Do you want to use the local module as a npm package dependencies or anything else?
here is the link if you want to do the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to explain it, But my question is resolved now.

Comment: Cool then, happy hacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow following Steps:

- Delete the node modules folder by running `rm -rf node_modules`
- Delete package.lock.json file by running `rm -f package-lock.json`
- Clean up the NPM cache by running `npm cache clean --force`
- Install all packages again by running `npm install`

Comment: Nevermind what I said earlier (If you saw it), This worked, Thank you so much!