# Create angular install package *without* using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, installation, offline

So I can't find a specific version of this particular problem. My problem is this. I work in a highly restricted work environment, I have one computer with npm package manager but *no* internet. I have another computer with internet but I *cannot* use npm to download files.

So I want to use the internet computer to prepare a tgz file for the offline computer to install angular and all its dependencies, so I can use those files as input for the offline computer to install these npm packages.

Using another computer that is off network to prepare packages is a non starter -- I cannot do it within the security constraints of the environment.

I have tried downloading the tgz files from angular directly but they are only like 150k so it's obvious I'm missing dependent packages and so forth. I have the source from github, but that seems like it would be a nightmare to setup and maintain.

What I'd like to do is use windows command line tools to generate a tgz file on the online computer, without the use of npm, to generate a fully resolved angular cli npm package to use as an input for the offline computer so it will...just work?

But so far it's been really tedious to get this done, and no matter how much I push back that it's dumb to not have npm on the online computer to get this done without a headache, management just doesn't understand. Any tips? Both boxes are windows fwiw. I can't install any custom command line tools whatsoever, so I just have windows out of the box basically.

Comment: work with local modules: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806241/how-to-specify-local-modules-as-npm-package-dependencies)

Comment: how...do I get the local modules even over there though? This doesn't seem to answer my question at all. Even getting the project dependencies to download and work with the project dependencies seems incredibly burdensome to even build out. Do I literally have to look through all the yarn (etc) files to build out a depdency graph and download all those packages separately? 

It's dumb I even have to do it this way, but I wish fully resolved npm package tars were available to install somewhere, that would make this process infinitely simpler.