# The best way to run npm install for nested folders?

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the most correct way to install `npm packages` in nested sub folders?

```
my-app
  /my-sub-module
  package.json
package.json
```

What is the best way to have `packages` in `/my-sub-module` be installed automatically when `npm install` run in `my-app`?

Comment: I think the most idiomatic thing is to have a single package.json file at the to of your project.

Comment: One idea would be to use an npm script that runs a bash file.

Comment: Could this not be done with a modificaiton to how local paths work?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to run a single command to install npm packages in nested subfolders, you can run a script via `npm` and main `package.json` in your root directory. The script will visit every subdirectory and run `npm install`.

Below is a `.js` script that will achieve the desired result:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var resolve = require('path').resolve;
var join = require('path').join;
var cp = require('child_process');
var os = require('os');
    
// get library path
var lib = resolve(__dirname, '../lib/');
    
fs.readdirSync(lib).forEach(function(mod) {
    var modPath = join(lib, mod);
    
    // ensure path has package.json
    if (!fs.existsSync(join(modPath, 'package.json'))) {
        return;
    }

    // npm binary based on OS
    var npmCmd = os.platform().startsWith('win') ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm';

    // install folder
    cp.spawn(npmCmd, ['i'], {
        env: process.env,
        cwd: modPath,
        stdio: 'inherit'
    });
})
```

Note that this is an example taken from a [StrongLoop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/modular-node-js-express/) article that specifically addresses a modular `node.js` project structure (including nested components and `package.json` files).

As suggested, you could also achieve the same thing with a bash script.

EDIT: Made the code work in Windows

Comment: To complicated right though, thanks for the article link.

Comment: While the 'component' based structure is quite a handy way to setup a node app, it's probably overkill in the early stages of the app to break out separate package.json files etc. The idea tends to come to fruition when the app grows and you legitimately want separate modules/services. But yes, definitely too complicated if not necessary.

Comment: While yes a bash script will do, but I prefer the nodejs way of doing it for maximum portability between Windows which has a DOS shell and Linux/Mac which has the Unix shell.

Answer (score 369):

I prefer using post-install, if you know the names of the nested subdir. In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "cd nested_dir && npm install",
  ...
}
```

Comment: what about multiple folders? "cd nested_dir && npm install && cd.. & cd nested_dir2 && npm install" ??

Comment: @Emre yes - that's it.

Comment: @Scott can't you then just put the next folder in the inside package.json like `"postinstall": "cd nested_dir2 && npm install"` for each folder?

Comment: @Aron What if you want two subdirectories within the name parent directory?

Comment: @Emre That should work, subshells might be slightly cleaner: "(cd nested_dir && npm install); (cd nested_dir2 && npm install); ..."

Comment: it makes much more sense this solution that the one selected, to me

Comment: make a batch (postinstall.bat) file that runs whatever you want

Comment: With multiple folders: `"postinstall": "yarn --cwd folderA install && yarn --cwd folderB install && ....`

Comment: This is indeed a very neat and compact solution! Gets my +1 for suggestd solution.

Comment: Time has passed. Use [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces), people.

Answer (score 113):

Per @Scott's answer, the install|postinstall script is the simplest way as long as sub-directory names are known. This is how I run it for multiple sub dirs. For example, pretend we have `api/`, `web/` and `shared/` sub-projects in a monorepo root:

```js
// In monorepo root package.json
{
...
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "(cd api && npm install); (cd web && npm install); (cd shared && npm install)"
  },
}
```

On Windows, replace the `;` between the parentesis with `&&`.

```js
// In monorepo root package.json
{
...
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "(cd api && npm install) && (cd web && npm install) && (cd shared && npm install)"
  },
}
```

Comment: will those npm installs happen one after eachother or all at the same time?

Comment: Good use of `( )` to create subshells and avoiding `cd api && npm install && cd ..`.

Comment: I get this error when running `npm install` at the top-level: `"(cd was unexpected at this time."`

Comment: My directories are nested at the same depth as each other relative to their parent directory so in my case I had to do it like this: `"(cd api && npm install); (cd ../web && npm install);...` including the `../` to make sure it changes the directory to the right one. I thought the parentheses would run the command in the same working directory context independently from each other as @CameronHudson said but for some reason, it didn't work for me...

Comment: As a super lazy approach (I admit): `"postinstall": "find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -path './.*' | xargs -Idest yarn --cwd dest install"`

Answer (score 63):

**Use Case 1**: If you want be able to run npm commands from within each subdirectory (where each package.json is), you will need to use `postinstall`.

As I often use `npm-run-all` anyway, I use it to keep it nice and short (the part in the postinstall):

```
{
    "install:demo": "cd projects/demo && npm install",
    "install:design": "cd projects/design && npm install",
    "install:utils": "cd projects/utils && npm install",

    "postinstall": "run-p install:*"
}
```

This has the added benefit that I can install all at once, or individually. If you don't need this or don't want `npm-run-all` as a dependency, check out demisx's answer (using subshells in postinstall).

**Use Case 2**: If you will be running all npm commands from the root directory (and, for example, won't be using npm scripts in subdirectories), you could simply install each subdirectory like you would any dependecy:

```
npm install path/to/any/directory/with/a/package-json
```

In the latter case, don't be surprised that you don't find any `node_modules` or `package-lock.json` file in the sub-directories - all packages will be installed in the root `node_modules`, which is why you won't be able to run your npm commands (that require dependencies) from any of your subdirectories.

If you're not sure, use case 1 always works.

Comment: It's nice to have each submodule have its own install script and then execute them all in postinstall. `run-p` is not necessary, but it's then more verbose `"postinstall": "npm run install:a && npm run install:b"`

Comment: Yes, you can use `&&` without `run-p`. But as you say, that's less readable. Another drawback (that run-p solves because installs run in parallel) is that if one fails, no other script is affected

Comment: FYI if you accidentally `cd` into a wrong path that doesn't contain `package.json` it will loop install script forever. Therefore I use `"install:mymodule": "cd src/mymodule && test -f package.json && npm install"`

Comment: @DonVaughn that's the point: `test -f package.json` will make `npm install` exit with `error tmp@1.0.0 install:module: cd module && test -f package.json && npm install npm ERR! Exit status 1`. Without that check it will loop forever without any clues for you to figure out where you've made a mistake. Try it yourself.

Comment: @DonVaughn I suppose you understand that to correct a mistake you need to know where the mistake is? Or at least that there is a mistake at all. That's the entire purpose of my adjustment. Without it 'npm install' won't throw any errors at you. That was my last comment in this thread, sorry.

Comment: use case 1 is the simplest most readable and imo best way to achieve this. thanks for that

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer works, but you can use `--prefix` to run npm commands in a selected location.

```
"postinstall": "npm --prefix ./nested_dir install"
```

And `--prefix` works for any npm command, not just `install`.

You can also view the current prefix with

```
npm prefix
```

And set your global install (-g) folder with

```
npm config set prefix "folder_path"
```

Maybe TMI, but you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks BJ I'm working in an nx project and your folder targeted npm install seems to have done the trick.. thanks :+1: Is it necessary to add the "postinstall" script command to the package.json so that the targeted npm install can run in a pipeline?

Answer (score 30):

Just for reference in case people come across this question. You can now:

- Add a package.json to a subfolder
- Install this subfolder as reference-link in the main package.json:

`npm install --save path/to/my/subfolder`

Comment: Note that dependencies are installed in the root folder. I suspect that if you are even considering this pattern, you want the dependencies of the sub-directory package.json in the sub-directory.

Comment: What do you mean? The dependencies for the subfolder-package are in the package.json in the subfolder.

Comment: (using npm v6.6.0 & node v8.15.0) - Setup up an example for yourself. `mkdir -p a/b ; cd a ; npm init ; cd b ; npm init ; npm install --save through2 ;` Now wait... you just *manually* installed dependencies in "b", that's not what happens when you clone a fresh project. `rm -rf node_modules ; cd .. ; npm install --save ./b`. Now list node_modules, then list b.

Comment: Ah you mean the modules. Yes, the node_modules for b will be installed in a/node_modules. Which makes sense, because you will require / include the modules as part of the main code, not as a "real" node module. So a "require('throug2')" would search through2 in a/node_modules.

Comment: I'm trying to do code generation and want a subfolder-package which is fully prepared to run, including its own node_modules.  If I find the solution, I'll make sure to update!

Comment: Directly running npm install within that folder worked, so the post-install script is very clean.  If I were to build the process into a node script, I'd recommend using `shelljs`!  Clean cross-platform support for free.

Comment: When you add this subfolder package to a project as a subfolder, the dependency modules will be added to the node_modules of the main project. If you add the subpackage parallel to the main project (i.e. they share a parent directory), the subpackage will have it's own node_modules. In that case you must run npm install manually for the subpackage.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work when installed transitively. `Could not install "path/to/my/subfolder" as it is not a directory and is not a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or .tar`

Comment: It should be a directory, containing your code and package.json file.

Comment: It does not install `node_modules` in the specified folder, but in the folder you are in

Comment: You shoud run nmp install in the top directory of your project, the one with the right package.json.

Answer (score 27):

My solution is very similar.
Pure Node.js

The following script examines all subfolders (recursively) as long as they have `package.json` and runs `npm install` in each of them.
One can add exceptions to it: folders allowed not having `package.json`. In the example below one such folder is "packages".
One can run it as a "preinstall" script.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const child_process = require('child_process')

const root = process.cwd()
npm_install_recursive(root)

// Since this script is intended to be run as a "preinstall" command,
// it will do `npm install` automatically inside the root folder in the end.
console.log('===================================================================')
console.log(`Performing "npm install" inside root folder`)
console.log('===================================================================')

// Recurses into a folder
function npm_install_recursive(folder)
{
    const has_package_json = fs.existsSync(path.join(folder, 'package.json'))

    // Abort if there's no `package.json` in this folder and it's not a "packages" folder
    if (!has_package_json && path.basename(folder) !== 'packages')
    {
        return
    }

    // If there is `package.json` in this folder then perform `npm install`.
    //
    // Since this script is intended to be run as a "preinstall" command,
    // skip the root folder, because it will be `npm install`ed in the end.
    // Hence the `folder !== root` condition.
    //
    if (has_package_json && folder !== root)
    {
        console.log('===================================================================')
        console.log(`Performing "npm install" inside ${folder === root ? 'root folder' : './' + path.relative(root, folder)}`)
        console.log('===================================================================')

        npm_install(folder)
    }

    // Recurse into subfolders
    for (let subfolder of subfolders(folder))
    {
        npm_install_recursive(subfolder)
    }
}

// Performs `npm install`
function npm_install(where)
{
    child_process.execSync('npm install', { cwd: where, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' })
}

// Lists subfolders in a folder
function subfolders(folder)
{
    return fs.readdirSync(folder)
        .filter(subfolder => fs.statSync(path.join(folder, subfolder)).isDirectory())
        .filter(subfolder => subfolder !== 'node_modules' && subfolder[0] !== '.')
        .map(subfolder => path.join(folder, subfolder))
}
```

Comment: your script is nice. However, for my personal purposes I prefer to remove the first 'if condition' to get a deep nested 'npm install'!

Answer (score 14):

If you have `find` utility on your system, you could try running the following command in your application root directory:
`find . ! -path "*/node_modules/*" -name "package.json" -execdir npm install \;`

Basically, find all `package.json` files and run `npm install` in that directory, skipping all `node_modules` directories.

Comment: Great answer. Just a note that you can also omit additional paths with: `find . ! -path "*/node_modules/*" ! -path "*/additional_path/*" -name "package.json" -execdir npm install \;`

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT** As mentioned by *fgblomqvist* in comments, **npm** now supports workspaces too: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/using-npm/workspaces

---

Some of the answers are quite old. I think nowadays we have some new options available to setup [monorepos](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md).

1. I would suggest using [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/):

> Workspaces are a new way to set up your package architecture that’s available by default starting from Yarn 1.0. It allows you to setup multiple packages in such a way that you only need to run `yarn install` once to install all of them in a single pass.

2. If you prefer or have to stay with **npm**, I suggest taking a look at [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna):

> Lerna is a tool that optimizes the workflow around managing multi-package repositories with git and npm.

lerna works perfect with yarn workspaces too - [article](https://velotio.medium.com/building-scalable-front-end-with-lerna-yarn-and-react-in-60-minutes-93320b6bf6f). I've just finished setting up a monorepo project - [example](https://github.com/klyakh/material-spirit/tree/prototyping).

And here is an example of a multi-package project configured to use npm + lerna - [MDC Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web): they run `lerna bootstrap` using package.json's `postinstall`.

Comment: Please don't use lerna, NPM has native support for "workspaces" now too: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces/

Answer (score 4):

**[For macOS, Linux users]:**

I created a bash file to install all dependencies in the project and nested folder.

```sh
find . -name node_modules -prune -o -name package.json -execdir npm install \;
```

**Explain:** In the root directory, exclude the `node_modules` folder (even inside nested folders), find the directory that has the `package.json` file then run the `npm install` command.

In case you just want to find on specified folders (eg: abc123, def456 folder), run as below:

```sh
find ./abc123/* ./def456/* -name node_modules -prune -o -name package.json -execdir npm install \;
```

Comment: That is the most helpful answer. Thank you! It should be the accepted one ☝️

Answer (score 3):

Adding Windows support to [snozza's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774097/727717) answer, as well as skipping of `node_modules` folder if present.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var resolve = require('path').resolve
var join = require('path').join
var cp = require('child_process')

// get library path
var lib = resolve(__dirname, '../lib/')

fs.readdirSync(lib)
  .forEach(function (mod) {
    var modPath = join(lib, mod)
    // ensure path has package.json
    if (!mod === 'node_modules' && !fs.existsSync(join(modPath, 'package.json'))) return

    // Determine OS and set command accordingly
    const cmd = /^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm';

    // install folder
    cp.spawn(cmd, ['i'], { env: process.env, cwd: modPath, stdio: 'inherit' })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the scripts provided here, I built a configurable example which:

- can be setup to use `yarn` or `npm`
- can be setup to determine the command to use based on lock files so that if you set it to use `yarn` but a directory only has a `package-lock.json` it will use `npm` for that directory (defaults to true).
- configure logging
- runs installations in parallel using `cp.spawn`
- can do dry runs to let you see what it would do first
- can be run as a function or auto run using env vars

  - when run as a function, optionally provide array of directories to check
- returns a promise that resolves when completed
- allows setting max depth to look if needed
- knows to stop recursing if it finds a folder with `yarn workspaces` (configurable)
- allows skipping directories using a comma separated env var or by passing the config an array of strings to match against or a function which receives the file name, file path, and the fs.Dirent obj and expects a boolean result.

```
const path = require('path');
const { promises: fs } = require('fs');
const cp = require('child_process');

// if you want to have it automatically run based upon
// process.cwd()
const AUTO_RUN = Boolean(process.env.RI_AUTO_RUN);

/**
 * Creates a config object from environment variables which can then be
 * overriden if executing via its exported function (config as second arg)
 */
const getConfig = (config = {}) => ({
  // we want to use yarn by default but RI_USE_YARN=false will
  // use npm instead
  useYarn: process.env.RI_USE_YARN !== 'false',
  // should we handle yarn workspaces?  if this is true (default)
  // then we will stop recursing if a package.json has the "workspaces"
  // property and we will allow `yarn` to do its thing.
  yarnWorkspaces: process.env.RI_YARN_WORKSPACES !== 'false',
  // if truthy, will run extra checks to see if there is a package-lock.json
  // or yarn.lock file in a given directory and use that installer if so.
  detectLockFiles: process.env.RI_DETECT_LOCK_FILES !== 'false',
  // what kind of logging should be done on the spawned processes?
  // if this exists and it is not errors it will log everything
  // otherwise it will only log stderr and spawn errors
  log: process.env.RI_LOG || 'errors',
  // max depth to recurse?
  maxDepth: process.env.RI_MAX_DEPTH || Infinity,
  // do not install at the root directory?
  ignoreRoot: Boolean(process.env.RI_IGNORE_ROOT),
  // an array (or comma separated string for env var) of directories
  // to skip while recursing. if array, can pass functions which
  // return a boolean after receiving the dir path and fs.Dirent args
  // @see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent
  skipDirectories: process.env.RI_SKIP_DIRS
    ? process.env.RI_SKIP_DIRS.split(',').map(str => str.trim())
    : undefined,
  // just run through and log the actions that would be taken?
  dry: Boolean(process.env.RI_DRY_RUN),
  ...config
});

function handleSpawnedProcess(dir, log, proc) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    proc.on('error', error => {
      console.log(`
----------------
  [RI] | [ERROR] | Failed to Spawn Process
  - Path:   ${dir}
  - Reason: ${error.message}
----------------
  `);
      reject(error);
    });

    if (log) {
      proc.stderr.on('data', data => {
        console.error(`[RI] | [${dir}] | ${data}`);
      });
    }

    if (log && log !== 'errors') {
      proc.stdout.on('data', data => {
        console.log(`[RI] | [${dir}] | ${data}`);
      });
    }

    proc.on('close', code => {
      if (log && log !== 'errors') {
        console.log(`
----------------
  [RI] | [COMPLETE] | Spawned Process Closed
  - Path: ${dir}
  - Code: ${code}
----------------
        `);
      }
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(
          new Error(
            `[RI] | [ERROR] | [${dir}] | failed to install with exit code ${code}`
          )
        );
      }
    });
  });
}

async function recurseDirectory(rootDir, config) {
  const {
    useYarn,
    yarnWorkspaces,
    detectLockFiles,
    log,
    maxDepth,
    ignoreRoot,
    skipDirectories,
    dry
  } = config;

  const installPromises = [];

  function install(cmd, folder, relativeDir) {
    const proc = cp.spawn(cmd, ['install'], {
      cwd: folder,
      env: process.env
    });
    installPromises.push(handleSpawnedProcess(relativeDir, log, proc));
  }

  function shouldSkipFile(filePath, file) {
    if (!file.isDirectory() || file.name === 'node_modules') {
      return true;
    }
    if (!skipDirectories) {
      return false;
    }
    return skipDirectories.some(check =>
      typeof check === 'function' ? check(filePath, file) : check === file.name
    );
  }

  async function getInstallCommand(folder) {
    let cmd = useYarn ? 'yarn' : 'npm';
    if (detectLockFiles) {
      const [hasYarnLock, hasPackageLock] = await Promise.all([
        fs
          .readFile(path.join(folder, 'yarn.lock'))
          .then(() => true)
          .catch(() => false),
        fs
          .readFile(path.join(folder, 'package-lock.json'))
          .then(() => true)
          .catch(() => false)
      ]);
      if (cmd === 'yarn' && !hasYarnLock && hasPackageLock) {
        cmd = 'npm';
      } else if (cmd === 'npm' && !hasPackageLock && hasYarnLock) {
        cmd = 'yarn';
      }
    }
    return cmd;
  }

  async function installRecursively(folder, depth = 0) {
    if (dry || (log && log !== 'errors')) {
      console.log('[RI] | Check Directory --> ', folder);
    }

    let pkg;

    if (folder !== rootDir || !ignoreRoot) {
      try {
        // Check if package.json exists, if it doesnt this will error and move on
        pkg = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(path.join(folder, 'package.json')));
        // get the command that we should use.  if lock checking is enabled it will
        // also determine what installer to use based on the available lock files
        const cmd = await getInstallCommand(folder);
        const relativeDir = `${path.basename(rootDir)} -> ./${path.relative(
          rootDir,
          folder
        )}`;
        if (dry || (log && log !== 'errors')) {
          console.log(
            `[RI] | Performing (${cmd} install) at path "${relativeDir}"`
          );
        }
        if (!dry) {
          install(cmd, folder, relativeDir);
        }
      } catch {
        // do nothing when error caught as it simply indicates package.json likely doesnt
        // exist.
      }
    }

    if (
      depth >= maxDepth ||
      (pkg && useYarn && yarnWorkspaces && pkg.workspaces)
    ) {
      // if we have reached maxDepth or if our package.json in the current directory
      // contains yarn workspaces then we use yarn for installing then this is the last
      // directory we will attempt to install.
      return;
    }

    const files = await fs.readdir(folder, { withFileTypes: true });

    return Promise.all(
      files.map(file => {
        const filePath = path.join(folder, file.name);
        return shouldSkipFile(filePath, file)
          ? undefined
          : installRecursively(filePath, depth + 1);
      })
    );
  }

  await installRecursively(rootDir);
  await Promise.all(installPromises);
}

async function startRecursiveInstall(directories, _config) {
  const config = getConfig(_config);
  const promise = Array.isArray(directories)
    ? Promise.all(directories.map(rootDir => recurseDirectory(rootDir, config)))
    : recurseDirectory(directories, config);
  await promise;
}

if (AUTO_RUN) {
  startRecursiveInstall(process.cwd());
}

module.exports = startRecursiveInstall;
```

---

And with it being used:

```
const installRecursively = require('./recursive-install');

installRecursively(process.cwd(), { dry: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && npm install" \;
```

Answer (score 2):

To run `npm install` on every subdirectory you can do something like:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "install:all": "for D in */; do npm install --cwd \"${D}\"; done"
}
```

where

`install:all` is just the name of the script, you can name it whatever you please

`D` Is the name of the directory at the current iteration

`*/` Specifies where you want to look for subdirectories. `directory/*/` will list all directories inside `directory/` and `directory/*/*/` will list all directories two levels in.

`npm install -cwd` install all dependencies in the given folder

You could also run several commands, for example:

`for D in */; do echo \"Installing stuff on ${D}\" && npm install --cwd \"${D}\"; done`

will print "Installing stuff on your_subfolder/" on every iteration.

This works for `yarn` too

Answer (score 0):

Any language that can get a list of directories and run shell commands can do this for you.

I know it isn't the answer OP was going for exactly, but it's one that will always work. You need to create an array of subdirectory names, then loop over them and run `npm i`, or whatever command you're needing to run.

For reference, I tried `npm i **/`, which just installed the modules from all the subdirectories in the parent. It's unintuitive as hell, but needless to say it's not the solution you need.