# Script in package.json to run more than one npm install?

Tags: npm, package.json

I want to run npm install in my  folder and subfolder without having to run:

1. npm install
2. cd subfolder
3. npm install

So, in this script I would run two `npm install` in one single command in my main folder without having to `cd` into the subfolder.
I know theres how to do it by placing a script on **package.json** but I forgot the script now.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, I could run all of the three commands using **&&**:

```
"scripts": {
    "yourscript": "npm install && cd subfolder && npm install"
}
```

Comment: Glad you find a solution. Might be relevant to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014050/how-to-do-recursive-installation-of-dependencies-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable name like this

```
scripts: {
 {
 "cmdthatyouwant": "nmp i; cd folder; npm i"
 }
}
```

Comment: Not working, I also replaced "i" for "install" and "nmp" for "npm", still didn't work