# Install NPM dependancies for sub package which is nested within my main project?

Tags: npm

I have a main package.json for my project. I also have a component within my project which I'm publishing to NPM, so that requires its own package.json.

```
package.json
index.html
-folder
--component-folder
---package.json
```

Both package.json files define dependancies. At the moment I have to run `npm install` from both my project root and from component-folder. Is there a way of making it install dependancies for both when its only run from the project root?

Comment: I think this is a similar enough issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773546/the-best-way-to-run-npm-install-for-nested-folders

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using subpackage:

```json
{
    "name": "my-awesome-project",
    "version": "2.5.1",
    "subPackages": [
        "packages/sub-package-1",
        "packages/sub-package-2"
    ]
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/subpackage