# Use NPM scripts to install dependancies into the relevant sub folder?

Tags: npm

I have a top level package.json file in my project and also one within a sub folder.

```
index.html
package.json
node_modules/
sub-folder/
sub-folder/package.json
sub-folder/node_modules/
```

I want to run a single command which will run npm install for both packages. In my top level package.json I have the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm install sub-folder",
```

This does install the dependancies from the package.json in my sub folder, however it installs them in my top level node_modules folder, not the one nested in the sub folder.

Do I need to use custom JavaScript as in the answer below? It seems overkill to do so as im so close:

[The best way to run npm install for nested folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773546/the-best-way-to-run-npm-install-for-nested-folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done it with this:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "cd .sub-folder && npm install",
```

"preinstall" means that when someone runs npm install from the root then this line will execute first. "start" is more often used to start applications rather than install dependancies.