# How to recursively uninstall all node_modules folders

Tags: node.js, recursion, npm, uninstallation

I have a pretty complicated project that has dependencies and sub dependencies. I have `git` submodules within my project that have `npm` dependencies within them.

Is there a quick and effective way to clean all of the `node_modules` folders in my project recursively?

Answer (score 1):

Just clear all dependencies you want to remove in your `package.json` file and then run `npm prune`.

Comment: I have `git` submodules within my project that have npm dependencies within them. On the highest level, what you said would work, or I could just delete my `node_modules` folder. But this wouldn't affect my submodules

Comment: I think this would help to remove all dependencies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773546/the-best-way-to-run-npm-install-for-nested-folders

Comment: Ah thanks. That's slightly convoluted, but does the job!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to get rid of the nested mess of node_modules there are a couple ways to do this:

1. install `rimraf` globally, then call `rimraf [directory-path]`
2. Select the folder in WIndows Explorer, hold Shift + Delete, it will recursively delete the folders
3. Upgrading to newer versions of Node and NPM collapse the folder structure so it's more linear, which is pretty awesome (this would be my recommended solution and how I solved it at my company)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using unix system, basically you can run this command `find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Or use this script https://gist.github.com/qutek/868c30f5d1e7ec03c7459e067444bd67

Just download it and make it executable `chmod +x clear-node-modules.sh` and run it `./clear-node-modules.sh`