# Angular 4 application having multiple package.json. which one this uses

Tags: angular, package.json

I am trying to open an existing angular 4 application to upgrade to angular 6 application.

the project structure is as follows:

```
-Core
----src
--------components
--------assets
--------pipes
--------package.json
--------index.ts
package.json
gulpfile.js
tsconfig.json
```

In the above structure, there is a package.json in both the root and inside src folder. I am not sure whether i can delete the one inside \src folder? From going through the code i can understand that this project is made as a module which is then linked to the main application using symbolic links.

Can anyone tell what is the use of multiple package.json here?

package.json inside src folder:

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "name",
    "email": "name@email.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo/issues"
  },
  "main": "index.umd.js",
  "module": "index.js",
  "jsnext:main": "index.js",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "primeng": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't think you need two, even if it's a component library should be with the main one. Unless I could see that the parent package.json is more for backend and project build etc, and the src one is specifically for front-end libs.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` will go through all the sub folders and run npm install. So basically if you run the `package.json` in the root directory, it will run the `package.json` inside sub directory as well.

[The best way to run npm install for nested folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773546/the-best-way-to-run-npm-install-for-nested-folders)