# nested package.json in Yarn workspaces

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

When using yarn workspaces is it possible to have nested `package.json` files to resolve dependancies for a subset of packages? Avoiding repetition?

where `cra` are create-react-apps and `pkg` are packages that these sites consume.
e.g.

```
| /
| - package.json
|---- /sites
|-------- /cra-1
|         - package.json
|-------- /cra-2
|         - package.json
|---- /packages
|     - package.json   // <<---- Extra level here
|-------- /pkg-1
|         - package.json
|-------- /pkg-1
|         - package.json
|-------- /pkg-2
|         - package.json
```

this would allow us to share common dependancies for our packages... keep them all in sync and up-to-date

Comment: Looks like the answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31774097/7452021

Comment: I dont think that is a valid answer really. Its not using the tool as its intended, its describing a custom script.