# How to use locally built NPM package in project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm new to NPM (obviously) and I have forked a NPM module to test out some custom modifications to it - let's call that project dependsOnMe. Now i want to use DependsOnMe in my CustomApp project. I can't figure out how to do this.

In my DependsOnMe project I did a npm install -g . (whatever that does, it's now unclear to me), but when I go to my CustomApp project and add a dependency for DependsOnMe into my package.json NPM tells me it cant find DependsOnMe in the NPM remote repo (no kidding...).

Since I installed DependsOnMe globally I thought perhaps I don't need to declare a dependency in MyCustomApp, but when I try to include DependsOnMe in one of my project's .js files I get the error that DependsOnMe cannot be found.

This must be simple, what am I missing?

Comment: As per my Knowledge you need to register and Publish package to npm and then install it with npm  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

Comment: Well, I see this suggestion, but it doesn't work either - it tells me it cant find the directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json

Comment: https://quickleft.com/blog/creating-and-publishing-a-node-js-module/

Comment: I got it working by including a local dependency as a relative path (was using absolute and it didn't work): 
    "DependsOnMe": "file:../../../../depends-on-me/"

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the DependsOnMe option