# Module not found error when trying to use a module as a local module

Tags: node.js, module, package.json

I am trying to understand as how to make a local module. At the root of node application, I have a directory named `lib`. Inside the lib directory I have a `.js` file which looks like:

```
var Test = function() {
    return {
        say : function() {
            console.log('Good morning!');
        }
    }
}();

module.exports = Test;
```

I have modified my `package.json` with an entry of the path to the local module:

```
"dependencies": {
   "chat-service": "^0.13.1",
   "greet-module": "file:lib/Test"
}
```

Now, if I try to run a test script like:

```
var greet = require('greet-module');

console.log(greet.say());
```

it throws an error saying:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'greet-module'
```

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modules.export` is incorrect. It should be `module.exports` with an `s`.

Also, make sure after you add the dependency to do an `npm install`. This will copy the file over to your `node_modules` and make it available to the `require` function.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json) for a good reference.

**Update:**

After going through some examples to figure this out I noticed, most projects have the structure I laid out below. You should probably format your local modules to be their own standalone packages. With their own folders and `package.json` files specifying their dependencies and name. Then you can include it with `npm install -S lib/test`.

It worked for me once I did it, and it'll be a good structure moving forward. Cheers.

[image]

See [here](https://github.com/Treeless/local-npm-dependency-example) for the code.

Comment: i think it should not be `modules.exports`, it should be `module.exports`

Comment: @MayankShukla Thanks, fixed. I always screw it up. Try that again OP.

Comment: @helloJSON See my addition.

Comment: @matt When I run `npm install` it throws `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/roger/nodejs/test/lib/test'` error. Although, there exists a file named `test.js` inside `lib` folder.

Comment: Try adding .js to your filename in the dependency object. Doesn't look like node is adding in the `.js` extension for you.

Comment: @helloJSON Sorry about all the troubleshooting, see my updated answer for a solution. Cheers.