# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve" using Local Paths

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, pixi.js

I'm trying to use [npm's "local paths" feature](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) but I'm getting the error:

> ERROR in ./src/pixi-environment/src/pixi-environment.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'pixi.js' in
>   '/Users/michaelosofsky/Developer/develop/locuslabs-js-sdk/src/pixi-environment/src'

I think I've set it all up correctly by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/2848676 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430086/2848676:

1. The local path relative to my project is ../../pixi.js_prerelease
2. From my project directory I installed with the command `npm install --save ~/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease`
3. My project's package.json got automatically updated with a dependency `"pixi.js": "file:../../pixi.js_prerelease",`
4. My project's `node_modules` directory automatically got a subdirectory called `pixi.js` created and it contains the files from `~/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease`
5. The file that imports `pixi.js` does it like this:

   `const PIXI         = require('pixi.js')`

I also tried these approaches:

`const PIXI         = require('./node_modules/pixi.js/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('./node_modules/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('../../../node_modules/pixi.js/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('../../../node_modules/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('~/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('~/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease')`

`const PIXI         = require('/Users/michaelosofsky/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease/pixi.js')`

`const PIXI         = require('/Users/michaelosofsky/Developer/pixi.js_prerelease')`

However, when I do `npm test` in my project's directory I get the error above.