# How to normalize my local packages to relative paths in package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) say that installing a dependency with a local path (e.g. `npm install ../module --save`) will normalize the dependency to a relative path in package.json, e.g.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
```

However, this appears to not be the case with v3+ as someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json#comment58272692_26028854).

This is how my path looks after `npm install ../myModule --save`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:///home/aFolder/Documents/git/project/modules/myModule"
  }
```

This path will only work on my system, and thus I need the relative path as seen in the first example. Seems like it would be a pretty common use case.

Is it possible to save dependencies with relative paths?