# How to include node_modules folder in VSCode Extension Package?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently building a VSCode extension (with `TypeScript`) where I need an external JS library that is not available in `npm` package manager. So, I have to manually add the external js package to the project.

The problem is that when I try to add the library to another folder except `node_modules`, `TypeScript` compiler tries to make `.map` file for the JS library. But I got a exception when `Typescript` tries to make the .map file (`FATAL ERROR, Out of Heap Memory` -- like that).

So, I put the external library to `node_module` folder (I know this is wrong, but can't see another option). Now everything is working file while debugging.

but when I try to build package through CLI - `vsce package` , the `node-module` package excluded even if I wrote `!node_modules/test/**` in `.vscodeignore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made local package of the library and installed it through NPM

For more : [Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json)