# How to use fork version of npm package in a project

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say there is an npm package called `abcd`.
Normally in `package.json`, we specified the dependencies as

    `"abcd": "^1.0.0",`

But this `abcd` does not work as expected, so I forked (and modified) it inside https://github.com/mygithubid/abcd

Then I run `npm install git+https://git@github.com/mygithubid/abcd.git` and in `package.json`, the definition is changed to

    `"abcd": "git+https://github.com/mygithubid/abcd.git",`

After restarting the project that using this `abcd`, now it throws error

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'abcd'`

... even though I saw the `abcd` folder is added inside `node_modules`

Could you advise the mistake I made in above? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install an npm package from GitHub directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly)

Comment: npm install github:mygithubid/abcd . check out

Comment: Actually the new `abcd` is added in `node_modules`, but the application still complaining of `Module not found: Can't resolve 'abcd'`

Comment: if you don't mind forking and downloading it locally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json

Comment: Thanks, Alon, it would be little problematic if I need to download locally... what I was trying is to fork in Github.com and modified in Github.com too. Is that not the common approach?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 34):

One fairly clean option is to use `patch-package`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

If the people using your project might use either npm or yarn, then remeber to make the patch available for both. More info under `patch-package --use-yarn`.

Patch or fork? See https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package#benefits-of-patching-over-forking

Answer (score 7):

Be sure that the github repository contains compiled files, at most cases you need build the package for npm first, the compiled files push only to NPM.
To find out how to build the package check the package.json file

Comment: can you provide more detailed steps to "find out how to build the packages" or refer to a guide at least?

Comment: @lacostenycoder it depends on the plugin itself. It is impossible to give an universal answer. Anyway, if you don't know where to start, you can open the `package.json` file and check the `scripts` property, it usually contains a `build` script.