# How to import forked echart

Tags: echarts

So far, I use the standard way to load from node_modules.

```
   import echarts from 'echarts'
```

Due to the my project requirement, I have to modify some tree layout source code and build my own echart.
And I am having difficult to import.

I tried three ways, all failed.

- import echart/dist folder
- import echart folder
- import echart.min.js

Could someone tell me the recommended way to import forked echarts？
Thank you very much.

Comment: Would this help? Sounds like you're trying to use a forked version of the module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122349

Answer (score 0):

I had the answer from echart developers.

https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16858#event-6405399579