# How to develop node library referenced via local directory from another project?

Tags: node.js, npm

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/62), when you reference a local dependency in `package.json` the local package will be copied to `node_modules`. This is not ideal when I'm developing a package and just referencing it from another project as I want to verify the library works correctly within another project. It seems every time I make a change to the library, I have to go back to my consuming project, delete the `node_modules/my-library` folder and rerun `npm install` each time for it to copy the library back. If I don't delete the folder first it doesn't seem to copy the latest version over.

If I develop directly inside `node_modules/my-library` it's not ideal because that folder isn't version controller, unlike the local folder referenced in `package.json`.

Another option would be to create an example project within the `my-library` repo, but I'd prefer to go that route as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to develop your library and have another project use the local version like so.

For example;

In the *my-library* directory run `npm link`.

Then in the project you want to use *my-libray* run `npm link my-library`.

This will also work with [yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/).