# Can't resolve Typescript module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have two Typescript react modules: `moduleA` and `moduleB`.

I am trying to use a component `Button.tsx` from `moduleA` by exporting the `Button.tsx` in `moduleB` referring to this component using `moduleA`.

Here's the steps I am following :

1. Installing and Configuring webpack and ts-loader in `moduleA`.
2. creating build using webpack of `moduleA`.
3. configuring the webpack and ts-loader in `moduleB`.
4. installing `moduleA` in `moduleB` using `npm install ../moduleA`.

Then, I am referring the `Button` component in `moduleB`, from `moduleA` using:

```ts
import { Button } from "moduleA";
```

I am getting this error :

```
ERROR in C:\Users\VaibhavPC\Projects\moduleb\src\Start.tsx
./src/Start.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\VaibhavPC\Projects\moduleb\src\Start.tsx(2,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './moduleA'
```

Here's my `package.json` of `moduleA`:

```
{
  "name": "moduleA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rm ./lib/* && tsc",
    "magic": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "test": "./test.sh"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.35",
    "@types/enzyme": "^2.7.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.40",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.23",
    "@types/sinon": "^1.16.36",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.12.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "LICENSE",
    "main.js"
  ],
  "types": "./lib/Button.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

and package.json of `moduleB`.

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rm ./lib/* && tsc",
    "magic": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "test": "./test.sh"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.35",
    "@types/enzyme": "^2.7.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.40",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.23",
    "@types/sinon": "^1.16.36",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.12.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "LICENSE",
    "main.js"
  ],
  "types": "./lib/hello.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "modulea": "file:../modulea",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.tsx",
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

folder structure:

```
├── dist
├── node_modules
├── src
├── package.json
├── webpack.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why not use `import { Button } from '../modulea'` instead of local npm package?

Comment: Another fix is using `npm link`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/3415716

Comment: @LeoCaseiro tried 'import { Button } from '../modulea'  did not work .

Comment: can you please post your `tsconfig.json` and the folder structure?

Comment: @LeoCaseiro edited . and also with npm link , same issue "can't resolve module".

Comment: It might be the `package.json` reference from your `main.js` which I assume is the name of webpack bundled after compilation.Perhaps if you set `{ "main": "./dist/main.js" }` on your `package.json` it'll find the right main file. Or wherever name set on webpack `output.filename`

Comment: Maybe it's better to recreate project using create-react-app?

Comment: Is linting throwing you an error ? or by running which command it is throwing error ?

Comment: Could you try restarting your editor / machine, this seems to be linting refresh issue.

Comment: I see that your `package` files simply list `main.js` for the `main` (entrypoint.) But `tsconfig` has an `outDir` of `dist`, try changing `main` to `./dist/main.js`

Answer (score 4):

This is because the package that is being used as a dependency is broken.

`moduleA` looks for the button in the wrong place. The `package.json` has the `main` property set to `"main.js"`. When the package is used, it tries to find the `main.js` file in the root directory. But according to your folder structure it does not exist.

As a verification step, go to `moduleB`'s `node_modules` folder and open `moduleA`, is there a `main.js` inside the folder?

It shouldn't exist because `tsconfig` has `outDir` set to `"./dist"`. The solution would be to change `moduleA`'s `main` to `"./dist/main.js"`

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly my issue.