# Alterting Node modules with Webpack and NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, file-structure

Lets say that I find an NPM package that works almost perfectly for my needs, however there is a little alteration that I need from it. Obviously when I do an NPM update or as such I don't want it to revert to whatever version was in my package json so I need to remove it from my dependency's.

Will Webpack know were to look for those specific node imports/requires or will I need to move the relevant files somewhere into my own project and alter said imports?

Comment: Let's put it this way: you can import the package, then override the function you want changed. Just do something like `thepackage.someFunction = () => { /* your version */ };`

Comment: the proper way would probably be to fork the repo on github, implement your changes, and reference it in your package json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json

Comment: @Pandelis Thanks!