# Share common React Native components across multiple apps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I'm going to have 2 separate React Apps in a single lerna/yarn workspaces repo which will need to use the same components.

What's the best way to reuse these components in multiple application without publishing it to a separate private NPM package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Locally

You could install the dependency from a local folder.

`npm install /path`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26028854/5508175

#### From a github repo

It is also possible to install from a GitHub repo

`npm install --save username/repo#branch-name`

https://link.medium.com/XYBpwAdRZS