# Installing a private package in an Angular 8 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have a private package on the file system that I'm trying to install in an Angular 8 project. So far with non-angular projects, this has worked fine. From the root of the Angular project I do:

```
npm i -S ../the-other-project-dependency/dist
```

The error message is:

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "../the-other-project-dependency/the-other-project-dependency" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

The part of this that is true is that `the-other-project-dependency` does not contain a `package.json` file.

The `package.json` file is in `../the-other-project-dependency/dist`.  Specifically, it is in the `dist` directory.

So I'm not sure if NPM is saying that the `dist` directory should be named `the-other-project-dependency`?

I tried renaming `dist` to `the-other-project-dependency` and now it gets passed that error, but it gives an error for another private project dependency:

Specifically it says:

```
`the-other-project-dependency/yet-another-private-dependency` could not be installed as it does not contain a `package.json` file.
```

So it looks as if NPM does not understand how to work with locally installed packages.  In this last case it seems as if it's saying the `yet-another-private-package-dependency` should be laid out as a sibling of `the-other-project-dependency` and it's not reading the file system path to that dependency.

I assumed [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json) that using local file deps should just work.

### Update

I think it's a bug in NPM.  [I filed a report here](https://npm.community/t/npm-is-generating-the-wrong-path-for-transitive-private-local-file-system-deps/8763)

### Resolution

Was able to get it working using yarn, but I had to remove the local private packages and reinstall them with yarn, as yarn uses a slightly different path string for local dependencies.

Comment: hmm the content of package.json in that dist folder may be important especially `main` property value as it tell npm what file to use as entry point to use. Also try `npm i file:../the-other-project-dependency/dist`

Comment: @Xesenix I think you are onto something.  I did not set up the `main` property  right.  I'm fixing it now, but running into some other compile errors so I"ll let you know if it works ASAP.

Comment: Hmm I fixed the `main` attribute,  but I still get the `package.json` not found message.  I don't get this if for example I install https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator locally from the `dist` folder.

Comment: OK - It has something to do with me including other private dependencies.  I stripped down the project to be dependency free, and it install fine.  I'll start with a brand new bare project and build it up with the other project dependencies, until I start hitting this error.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with private transitive dependencies.  For example if we have package `privateA` that depends on `privateB` and we install private A in the Angular project, it works as long as `privateA` does not depend on `privateB`.  When `privateB` is installed in `privateA` and an attempt is made to install `privateA` in the Angular project npm will complain that it cannot install `privateB` ...

Comment: I think its an NPM Bug: https://npm.community/t/npm-is-generating-the-wrong-path-for-transitive-private-local-file-system-deps/8763